# Google Sheet importxml tr td

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath

https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/5232/leon-fuat-berhad
[image]

Above is the website that I'm using, wish to import the row P/E, just want to import the value (6). The code that I write is =IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/5232/leon-fuat-berhad", "//td[contains(@class,'number')]") it pulls the entire value on the right side however I just want to only select the P/E number which I'm struggling to do so. How to edit the code to only select the P/E value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ultimately depends on how many details you are comfortable embedding in your XPath expression regarding the document's structure and literals.  For example this retrieves your P/E value of 6:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/5232/leon-fuat-berhad", "//table[contains(@class,'stock_details')]//td[@title='Price to Earning Ratio']/following-sibling::td[1]/text()")
```

With an XPath expression that first selects the table that contains the  "stock_details" class and then selects a td within the table that has title="Price to Earning Ratio" and then selects the text of the immediately next (first following) td element.

Or you could identify that following td (with the 6) using class as you originally tried:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/5232/leon-fuat-berhad", "//table[contains(@class,'stock_details')]//td[@title='Price to Earning Ratio']/following-sibling::td[@class='number']/text()")
```

and other similar approaches depending on which literal/structure assumptions you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation step by step on how to extract the wanted value. 

I tried both of the code that you attached, the first is working fine, for the second one I think it should be (I edited by following the class extraction method you showed in the first alternative):

=IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/5232/leon-fuat-berhad", "//table[contains(@class,'stock_details')]//td[@title='Price to Earning Ratio']/following-sibling::td[contains(@class,'number')]/text()")

Comment: `@class='number'` should work fine if the class attribute only ever has one value.  The contains is fine too, perhaps more flexible.  If you're having trouble with the second example it may be because I accidentally left double-quotes around "number" instead of single-quotes.  I'll correct that typo now.  Thanks.

Comment: Yea, after changed to single quotes it works fine. Now I understand more about the class attribute. Thanks again ^^

Answer (score 1):

Another method to extract the value using `index` and `xml` path

```
=index(IMPORTXML("https://www.klsescreener.com/v2/stocks/view/5232/leon-fuat-berhad", "//div[@class ='table-responsive']//table[1]/tbody/tr[9]/td[2]"),1)
```

Comment: Thank you for stating another alternative on how to extract the wanted value, it is a sad case where I can't tick two replies as answers.

Comment: It is fine, I always want to refresh how to extract data using importXML :)